# ¿Como crear una variable nueva en controlador de laravel-blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

**Soy nuevo en Laravel-Blade, necesito agregar la variable $cargos en el controlador de mi web para que me funcione un "opción value". Si alguien puede guiarme se lo agradecería enormemente. me gustaría que me guíen como para saber que código agregar al controlador o dentro de que otro archivo agregar mas código.**

*Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum*

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

__**Este es mi view actual**:

```
    <div class="tabla__controles">
        @if($concejales->hasPages())
        <div class="tabla__paginador">
            @if ($concejales->onFirstPage())
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" wire:click="previousPage" disabled>
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
                </button>
            @else
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" wire:click="previousPage">
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
                </button>
            @endif

            <span class="mx-2">Página {{ $concejales->currentPage() }} de {{ $concejales->lastPage() }} 
    </span>

            @if (!$concejales->hasMorePages())
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" wire:click="nextPage" disabled>
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </button>
            @else
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" wire:click="nextPage">
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </button>
            @endif
        </div>
        @endif

        @if(count($bloques) > 0)
        <div class="lista-tarjetas__bloques">
            <select wire:model="bloque" wire:change="resetearPagina()" class="tabla__buscador form- 
   control form-control-sm">
                <option value="todos" selected>Todos los bloques</option>
                @foreach ($bloques as $bloque)
                    <option value="{{ $bloque['id'] }}">{{ $bloque['nombre'] }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    

      <!-- <div class="lista-tarjetas__bloques">
            <select wire:model="cargo" wire:change="resetearPagina()" class="tabla__buscador form-control 
    form-control-sm">
                <option value="todos" selected>Todos</option>
                @foreach ($cargos as $cargo)
                    <option value="{{ $cargohcd['id'] }}">{{ $cargohcd['nombre'] }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div> -->
        
        @endif
    </div>

    @if(count($concejales) > 0)
        <div
            style="height: 85%; width: 100%;" 
            class="lista-tarjetas">

        @foreach ($concejales as $concejal)
            <div class="card tarjeta-concejal" style="background-color: #015875; color:#ffffff">
                <!--<b> <font size=2>{{ $concejal['tipo_autoridad'] }}</font></b>
                        </span>-->
                <img src=" {{ asset('/img/users_img.png') }}" class="card-img-top" style="width: 30px" 
    alt="Foto de {{ $concejal['concejal'] }}">

                <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-center" style="text-align:center">
                    <p class="card-title font-weight-bold">{{ $concejal['concejal'] }}</p>

                    <span class="card-text">{{ $concejal['distrito_nombre'] }}</span>
                    
                    @if ($concejal['bloque_nombre'] != null)
                        <span
                            class="tarjeta-concejal--texto-largo"
                            style="color: {{ $concejal['bloque_color'] }}">
                            <b>{{ $concejal['bloque_nombre'] }}</b>
                        </span>
                    @endif

                    <span>{{ $concejal['mandato_inicio'] }} - {{ $concejal['mandato_fin'] }}</span>
                    <br> <span>
                        
                        <b> <font size=2>{{ $concejal['tipo_autoridad'] }}</font></b>
                        </span>
                    <span>
                        
                         <font size=1> {{$concejal ['localidad']}}</font>
                        </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        </div>
    @else
        <div
            style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" 
            class="lista-tarjetas lista-tarjetas--vacia">
            <div class="lista-tarjetas--mensaje">
                <h2>Sin concejales</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
    </div>
```

**___Este es mi el codigo de mi controlador actual:**

````
```
private $CONCEJALES_VISIBLES = 6;
private $concejales;

public $bloque = 'todos';
public $distrito = null;
public $seccion = null;
public $bloques;

protected $listeners = [
    'municipioActualizado',
    'seccionActualizada'
];

public function render()
{
    $this->concejales = $this->cargarConcejales($this->bloque, $this->distrito, $this->seccion);
    $this->bloques = $this->bloques($this->distrito, $this->seccion);
    return view(
        'livewire.lista-concejales',
        [
            'concejales' => $this->concejales
        ]
    );
}


public function municipioActualizado($municipio) {
    $this->distrito = $municipio;
    $this->seccion = null;
    $this->bloque = 'todos';
    $this->resetearPagina();
}

public function seccionActualizada($seccion) {
    $this->distrito = null;
    $this->seccion = $seccion;
    $this->bloque = 'todos';
    $this->resetearPagina();
}

private function cargarConcejales($bloque, $distrito, $seccion) {
    $consulta = ConcejoDeliberante::
        leftJoin('bloques', 'bloques.id', '=', 'concejo_deliberantes.bloque_id')
        ->select(
            'concejo_deliberantes.*',
            'bloques.nombre as bloque_nombre',
            'bloques.color as bloque_color'
        );
    
    $consulta = $bloque == 'todos'
        ? $consulta
        : $consulta->where('concejo_deliberantes.bloque_id', '=', $bloque);
    
    if (!is_null($distrito)) {
        $consulta = $consulta->where('concejo_deliberantes.distrito_id', '=', $distrito);
    } else if (!is_null($seccion)) {
        $distritos = Distrito::
            where('seccion_id', '=', $this->seccion)
            ->select('id')
            ->get();
        $consulta = $consulta->whereIn('concejo_deliberantes.distrito_id', $distritos);
    }

    return $consulta->paginate($this->CONCEJALES_VISIBLES);
}

/**
 * Retorna los bloques ordenados por nombre. Si idDistrito != null devuelve solo
 * los bloques de ese distrito.
 */
private function bloques($distrito, $seccion) {
    return $this->consultaBloques($distrito, $seccion)
        ->orderBy('bloques.nombre')
        ->get();
}

private function consultaBloques($distrito, $seccion) {
    $consulta = ConcejoDeliberante::
        leftJoin('bloques', 'concejo_deliberantes.bloque_id', '=', 'bloques.id')
        ->select('bloques.*', DB::raw('count(bloques.id) as concejales'))
        ->where('bloques.estado', '=', 'ACTIVO');

    if (!is_null($distrito)) {
        $consulta = $consulta->where('concejo_deliberantes.distrito_id', '=', $distrito);
    } else if (!is_null($seccion)) {
        $distritos = Distrito::
            where('seccion_id', '=', $this->seccion)
            ->select('id')
            ->get();
        $consulta = $consulta->whereIn('concejo_deliberantes.distrito_id', $distritos);
    }

    return $consulta
        ->groupBy('bloques.id');
}

public function resetearPagina()
{
    $this->resetPage();
}
````

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/77rHS.png
```

Comment: ¿Y de dónde llega dicha variable?

Comment: Eso es lo que necesito saber, cómo crear la variable necesaria y donde

Comment: Pues si estas usando Livewire va en la clase del componente

Comment: Es lo que no se... como crearlo

Comment: Para eso se creó la documentación (*la cual te recomiendo leer*) https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties